# Is it possible to get ISO9796-2 signature with Trailer = 'BC' in Javacard?

Tags: java, cryptography, sign, javacard, emv

I trying to get the RSA signature as described in Annex A2.1 of EMV book 2.
As I understand it was described in ISO9796-2 as scheme 1, option 1.
So, the resulting signature should contain a Header equal to '6A' and a Trailer equal to 'BC'.

The algorithms ALG_RSA_SHA_ISO9796 and ALG_RSA_SHA_ISO9796_MR are the only suitable that I could find. But they acting like scheme 1, option 2 with a Trailer equal to '33cc'

Is it possible to get a signature with Trailer = 'BC'?

Javacard example code:

```
byte[] icc_modulus         = new byte[] {(byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0x7f, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x60, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x9a, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0x39};
byte[] icc_publicExponent  = new byte[] {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x03};
byte[] icc_privateExponent = new byte[] {(byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0xb3, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x8b};
byte[] icc_prime1          = new byte[] {(byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0x5d};
byte[] icc_prime2          = new byte[] {(byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x8d};
byte[] icc_exponent1       = new byte[] {(byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0xc0, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0x8e, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x93};
byte[] icc_exponent2       = new byte[] {(byte) 0x85, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0xe2, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0xb3, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xb3};
byte[] icc_coefficient     = new byte[] {(byte) 0x85, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x8e};

RSAPrivateCrtKey crtKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_CRT_PRIVATE, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_1024, false);
crtKey.clearKey();
crtKey.setP(icc_prime1, (short) 0, (short)icc_prime1.length);
crtKey.setQ(icc_prime2, (short) 0, (short)icc_prime2.length);
crtKey.setDP1(icc_exponent1, (short) 0, (short)icc_exponent1.length);
crtKey.setDQ1(icc_exponent2, (short) 0, (short)icc_exponent2.length);
crtKey.setPQ(icc_coefficient, (short) 0, (short)icc_coefficient.length);

short N = (short)icc_modulus.length;

byte[] in = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)(N-22), JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
byte[] out = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(N, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(in, (short) 0, (short) (N-22), (byte)0xBB);
in[0] = (byte)0xA1;
in[1] = (byte)0xA2;
in[2] = (byte)0xA3;


Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_RSA_SHA_ISO9796, false);
sig.init(crtKey, Signature.MODE_SIGN);
short sigLen = sig.sign(in, (short)0, (short)(N-22), out, (short) 0);
```

To verify signature I use OpenSSL:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -raw -inkey icc_key.pem -in sig_file.bin
```

- message = a1a2a3bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
- signature = 6aa1a2a3bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb8313b42003699d54fbe069fa294a596d6f47864333cc
- header = 6A
- trailer = 33CC   <- I need a trailer to be equal to 'BC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate such signature using `Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD` in decrypt mode.

Pseudocode:

```
RSAPrivateCrtKey privateKey = ...;
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);
cipher.init(privateKey, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

// Make signature (X being size of modulus in bytes)
byte[] inputBuffer,outputBuffer = ...;
inputBuffer[0]=(byte)0x6A;
inputBuffer[1..X-2]=...rest of your data;
inputBuffer[X-1]=(byte)0xBC;
cipher.doFinal(inputBuffer, (short)0, X, inputBuffer, outputBuffer, outputOffset);
```

Good luck with your project!